# WebPro.js Form Analytics Event tracking?

Tags: forms, google-analytics, adobe, muse

I'm trying to find out if it is possible to implement an Analytics Event to track conversions in the Muse WebPro.js Form widget on successful submit?

Here is the code from the Muse WebPro.js that executes the Form submit:

```
Muse.Utils.initWidget('#widgetu2128', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) {
    return new WebPro.Widget.Form(elem, {
        validationEvent: 'submit',
        errorStateSensitivity: 'high',
        fieldWrapperClass: 'fld-grp',
        formSubmittedClass: 'frm-sub-st',
        formErrorClass: 'frm-subm-err-st',
        formDeliveredClass: 'frm-subm-ok-st',
        notEmptyClass: 'non-empty-st',
        focusClass: 'focus-st',
        invalidClass: 'fld-err-st',
        requiredClass: 'fld-err-st',
        ajaxSubmit: true
    });
}); /* #widgetu2128 */
```

My idea is to insert the Analytics Event tracking code here, as example here:

```
Muse.Utils.initWidget('#widgetu2128', ['#bp_infinity'], function(elem) {
    return new WebPro.Widget.Form(elem, {
        validationEvent: 'submit',
        errorStateSensitivity: 'high',
        fieldWrapperClass: 'fld-grp',
        formSubmittedClass: 'frm-sub-st',
        formErrorClass: 'frm-subm-err-st',
        formDeliveredClass: 'frm-subm-ok-st',
        notEmptyClass: 'non-empty-st',
        focusClass: 'focus-st',
        invalidClass: 'fld-err-st',
        requiredClass: 'fld-err-st',
        onSuccess: function(){
            ga('send', 'event', 'Form', 'Send', '');
        },
        ajaxSubmit: true
    });
}); /* #widgetu2128 */
```

But it does not seem to be working. Anybody have any suggestions. Can't find any WebPro.js docs or support about this topic online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
 //validate

Muse.Utils.initWidget('#widgetu812', function(elem) { 
  new WebPro.Widget.Form(elem, 
  {
      validationEvent:'submit',
      errorStateSensitivity:'high',
      fieldWrapperClass:'fld-grp',
      formSubmittedClass:'frm-sub-st',
      formErrorClass:'frm-subm-err-st',
      formDeliveredClass:'frm-subm-ok-st',
      notEmptyClass:'non-empty-st',
      focusClass:'focus-st',
      invalidClass:'fld-err-st',
      requiredClass:'fld-err-st',
      ajaxSubmit:true
   }
  );
});/* #widgetu812 */

//submit

<script> $(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#widgetu812").ajaxComplete(function() {   
       if (typeof ga !== 'undefined') {       
         ga('send','event','order','sent');   
       }
 }); }); </script>
```